# How do I open multiple files from find each in a separate tab in vim?

Tags: invocation, tabbed-user-interface, load

I would like to find multiple files and open them all in tabs within the same vim instance.

Comment: [How to `locate` multiple files and open them in vim?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45782)

Comment: @gits not a duplicate question because I would like to use the `find` command and return multiple files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
vim -p `find . -name '*.txt'`
```

Putting the `find` command between backticks executes `find` before running the full command and the results replace what's between the backticks. So before running the full command it will have this form `vim -p result1 result2 ... resultN` .

Comment: This seems to fail if the filenames contain spaces.

Answer (score 5):

```
find "$PWD" -name '*.txt' -exec vim -p {} +
```

Comment: `vim -p \`find . -name '*.txt'\``

Comment: I like that more.  If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Ok, will do that.

Comment: This is the better way. The other way is easily broken if filenames have spaces, or special characters in them.

Comment: This approach (using the -exec switch) seems to work also when files contain spaces.